# Type hint conditional variadic application

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting, mypy

I am trying to type-hint the partial application of a constructor, which gets fully applied once a "tag" instance is supplied. This is implemented via a wrapping class, which stores the constructor and any partially applied arguments. Since the wrapper is for several types, it has to take variadic `*args`.

This creates two cases, which differ by the arguments they take:

1. Apply: `(tag: Tag, ...) -> Cls`
2. Store: `(...) -> Partial[Cls]`

Notably, the 2. case may or may not receive a first parameter. Both overlap in their arity, since they are variadic. This is straightforward to implement. I have tried to type-hint these using `@overload`:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

#: the class to partially construct
Cls = TypeVar('Cls')

class Tag:
    """Instances of this class complete the partial application"""

class Partial(Generic[Cls]):
    """Partially construct ``ctor`` until a :py:class:`~.Tag` is applied"""
    def __init__(self, ctor: Type[Cls], *args):
        self.ctor = ctor
        self.args = args

    # type hints
    @overload
    def __call__(self, tag: Tag, *args) -> Cls:
        ...

    @overload
    def __call__(self, *args) -> 'Partial[Cls]':
        ...

    # implementation
    def __call__(self, *args):
        if args and isinstance(args[0], Tag):
            return self.ctor(args[0], *self.args, *args[1:])
        return Partial(self.ctor, *self.args, *args)
```

However, neither mypy nor PyCharm are happy with this (PyCharm needs an explicit method call at the moment, but that is not my problem). Expanding the second overload with an explicit non-tag `(tag: Any, ...) -> Partial[Cls]` does not fix the issue. Both tools either report a type mismatch, incompatible overload, or fall back to `Any` or `Union`.

What is the correct annotation for this scenario?

---

Type check code example:

```
class VariadicString(str):
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        return str(args)


a = RecursivePartial(VariadicString, 1, 2, 3)
b = a(4, 5, 6)
c = b(Tag(), 7, 8, 9)
reveal_locals()  # absent for PyCharm
```

`mypy` correctly identifies the types of `a`, `b` and `c`, but rejects the program due to incompatible overload overlapping:

```
test.py:17: error: Overloaded function signatures 1 and 2 overlap with incompatible return types
test.py:38: error: Revealed local types are:
test.py:38: error: a: test.Partial[test.VariadicString*]
test.py:38: error: b: test,Partial[test.VariadicString*]
test.py:38: error: c: test.VariadicString*
```

PyCharm does not reject the program, but misidentifies `c` as a `Union` of *both* return types:

```
a: Partial[VariadicString]
b: Partial[VariadicString]
c: Union[VariadicString, Partial[VariadicString]]
```

Comment: What does `Partial` do that `functools.partial` does not?

Comment: @chepner ``Partial`` is self-applying on non-sealing application, allowing for further partial applications (it effectively curries ``ctor``). The sealing is more akin to ``partialmethod``, but binds explicitly on application instead of ``__get__``. We use it for incrementally preparing instance prototypes before binding them in a DAG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a typing expert but I don't think you'll be able to get this to work with just changing the type hinting. Mypy has no way of knowing which of the overloaded methods is being called when a Tag is included because it could fall into either use case.

For example, as it stands your code would allow for the passing of Tag variables to the `*args` variables in either case, so there is nothing in the type hinting to tell a user that you can't try to construct a partial instance storing several Tag variables.

I don't know if this is possible for your solution but since you're already doing a manual check on the type of the first `args` variable, you could insist that the method is either called with a Tag or an explicit None, changing the second overload to:

```
@overload
    def __call__(self, tag: None, *args) -> 'Partial[Cls]':
        ...
```

and the implementation to:

```
# implementation
def __call__(self, *args):
    if args and isinstance(args[0], Tag):
        return self.ctor(args[0], *self.args, *args[1:])
    # Don't add the None to the args.
    return Partial(self.ctor, *self.args, *args[1:])
```

Comment: mypy does know which case applies, and correctly deduces the return type. It picks the first matching case, which is also the most concrete. The problem with mypy is that it insists on the return types being compatible. I would not mind specifying `*args` or `args[0]` as „not Tag“ but do not know how.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I believe mypy throws the error regarding incompatible types because it has no way of knowing that a user will never expect the second case to be the one called when giving args of type Tag. I looked into declaring a variable as not a type but couldn’t find anything in the docs.